# Using dplyr::full_join inside a function

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I'm trying to make a function that takes a `data.frame` and a `character/factor vector` as inputs to create a joined dataframe. I've dug around SO for a while now, and reviewed Wickham's [Programming with DPLYR](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html#user-supplied-data), but to no avail.  The function seems to work for creating 'hires' and 'exits' but the join does not, with error stating it can't find my input vector.
Typically, the error I get states that R cannot find the input vector, such as:

```
Error in structure(names = !!x, .Data = "year") : object 'Gender' not found
```

or

```
Error in structure(names = x, .Data = "year") : object 'Gender' not found
```

Can you offer a solution that creates `final` and returns it to the environment?

```
 df<-structure(list(hireyear = c(2023L, 2022L, 2023L, 2023L, 2023L, NA), exityear = c(NA_integer_, 2024L, 2024L, 2024L, 2023L, NA_integer_), Gender = c("Female", "Female", "Female",       "Female", "Female", NA)), row.names = c("2377", "2378", "2379", "2380", "2381", "NA"), class = "data.frame")


attrit<-function(data,x){

hires<- data %>% 
group_by(hireyear,{{x}}) %>%   summarise(NumberHired=n()) %>%
rename(year=hireyear) %>%  as.data.frame()
hires$NumberHired<-ifelse(is.na(hires$NumberHired),0,hires$NumberHired)

exits<- data %>% 
group_by(exityear,{{x}}) %>%   summarise(NumberExited=n()) %>%
rename(year=exityear) %>%  as.data.frame()

 exits$NumberExited<-ifelse(is.na(exits$NumberExited),0,exits$NumberExited) # replace NA with 0 for "exits"

exits<-exits %>% filter(!is.na(year) & year!="") 

final<-full_join(hires, exits,
      # can't get either of the following to work....     
      #by=c("year",{{x}}) %>%
      #by =setNames("year",x)) %>%
      #by = structure(names =!!x, .Data = 'year') ) %>% 
# this order is important; pick one factor at a time?
      arrange(year,{{x}}) 

return(final)

} 

  attrit(df,Gender)
```

Comment: Can you please post your error message? Also I would not use `c` as a variable since that is the base R function for creating lists and vectors.

Comment: By using the `{{`  operator you are tunneling an unquoted expression into the `by` argument (e.g. `by = c("year", Gender)`) when the by argument takes a *character* vector (e.g. `by = c("year", "Gender")` -- notice the quotes). This may be part of the problem, but the error message would be helpful.

Comment: Also, `exits %>% filter(!is.na(year) & year!="")` is returning an empty data frame. All of the rows in your example data are filtered out by this and so there is nothing to join anyway.

Comment: I updated the question with examples of error messages.  Added exityear values as well. Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(rlang)

attrit<-function(data,x){
  
  hires<- data %>% 
    group_by(hireyear,{{x}}) %>%   summarise(NumberHired=n()) %>%
    rename(year=hireyear) %>%  as.data.frame()
  hires$NumberHired<-ifelse(is.na(hires$NumberHired),0,hires$NumberHired)
  
  exits<- data %>% 
    group_by(exityear,{{x}}) %>%   summarise(NumberExited=n()) %>%
    rename(year=exityear) %>%  as.data.frame()
  
  exits$NumberExited<-ifelse(is.na(exits$NumberExited),0,exits$NumberExited) # replace NA with 0 for "exits"
  
  exits<-exits %>% filter(!is.na(year) & year!="") 
  
  final<-full_join(hires, exits,
                   # can't get either of the following to work....     
                   by=c("year", as_string(ensym(x)))) %>%
                   arrange(year,{{x}}) 
                   
                   return(final)
                   
}
```

As I mentioned in the comments, `{{` is tunneling your unquoted expression directly to `by`. So the `full_join` "sees" `by = c("year", Gender)`. While you know `Gender` is a variable in your data frame, this is trying to search your environment for a variable named `Gender` which is cannot find because it has not been assigned, hence the error message.

Instead we need to convert the symbol into a character, which is what I have done using `as_string(ensym())`.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `enquo()` and `as_name()`.

```
library(dplyr)

mydf<-structure(list(hireyear = c(2023L, 2022L, 2023L, 2023L, 2023L, NA), exityear = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), Gender = c("Female", "Female", "Female",       "Female", "Female", NA)), row.names = c("2377", "2378", "2379", "2380", "2381", "NA"), class = "data.frame")


attrit<-function(data,x){
  hires<- data %>% 
    group_by(hireyear,{{x}}) %>%   summarise(NumberHired=n()) %>%
    rename(year=hireyear) %>%  as.data.frame()
  hires$NumberHired<-ifelse(is.na(hires$NumberHired),0,hires$NumberHired)
  
  exits<- data %>% 
    group_by(exityear,{{x}}) %>%   summarise(NumberExited=n()) %>%
    rename(year=exityear) %>%  as.data.frame()
  
  exits$NumberExited<-ifelse(is.na(exits$NumberExited),0,exits$NumberExited) # replace NA with 0 for "exits"
  
  exits<-exits %>% filter(!is.na(year) & year!="") 
  
  full_join(hires, exits, by=c("year", rlang::as_name(enquo(x)))) %>%
    arrange(year,{{x}})
} 

attrit(mydf,Gender)
```

As an aside, you don't need to store your output into its own object and use `return()` to return it.

Comment: Thanks @Phil.  Earlier, I had used ` as_name`  and `enquo` separately but not together.